# Is there any IPA TTS software that also considers tone

Tags: ipa, pronunciation, software

I want to create audio files for a conlect of Chinese I am studying, and therefore tone is one aspect I have to consider. Many of the IPA to speech software I've seen so far don't consider tone (or maybe I'm not inputting it right; I've tried inputting the tone letters after the IPA), so I can't use them. Do anyone know a program that does? Cheers